# passing the url property to model not working

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-model

I have a simple inheritance hierarchy of Backbone views, and want all of my views to have one generic model. Only the url property of the model in these views will differ. so I pass the url when initializing the model.

The parent generic view is:

```
GenericView = Backbone.View.extend({
template: "friendsList-template.html",
initialize: function(){
    var that = this;
    that.model.fetch({
        success: function(model,response){
            that.handleResponse(response);
        },
        error: function(){
            //handle error
        }
    });
}
});
```

And the child view is:

```
PersonView = GenericView.extend({
el:$("#container"),

personData: {},
template: "profile-template.html",
model = new GenericModel({
    url:"testRouter.php"
});//here is where I'm defining the url
initialize: function(){
    PersonView.__super__.initialize.apply(this);
},
render: function(){
    var that = this;
    $.get(this.templatesPath + this.template, function(resTemplate){
        var html = Mustache.render(resTemplate, that.personData);
        that.$el.html(html);
    });
},
handleResponse: function(res){
    this.personData = res;
    this.render();
}
});
```

And the GenericModel is simply empty model (for now at least)

```
GenericModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
});
```

In console, I'm getting the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: A "url" property or function must be specified backbone.js:1559
```

Is my hierarchy is the problem or something else? Any thoughts?

Comment: Had to edit it, I was trying out things and pasted the wrong version of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-constructor):

> **constructor / initialize** `new Model([attributes], [options])`
>   [...]
>   `{url: "..."}` and/or `{urlRoot: "..."}` options may be passed when creating a new model that needs to have a custom one-off URL endpoint.

Note two things:

1. The first argument to the constructor is the attributes object.
2. The `url` goes in the second `options` object.

So you should be doing this:

```
var model = new GenericModel(null, {
    url: "testRouter.php"
});
```

if you want to set the `url` when you create the model.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/gSYug/